# make own ios app, test on phone, free

Tags: xcode, export

I made my first app in xcode.

I am trying to export it as an app file and see it run on my iphone.

I cannot find a way to do this.  Searches lead me to "ad hoc provisioning," which wants me to pay $99 to sign up for.

Am I missing something?

I would like to export this app onto my iphone and see it work.

I don't mind registering for something but I don't want to pay anything.

Comment: Have a look here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ConfiguringYourApp/ConfiguringYourApp.html

Comment: I did "archive" and I can view the "organizer" page.  But I cannot seem to get from here to exporting it to an .app file, or get it onto my phone in any way.

Comment: Don't create an archive. While your device is connected physically, simply run your application.